# I can't access facebook.com/insights. Page has no content

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I want to get insights of my Webpage (not facebook page) on Facebook. In other words, track sharing and likes of my page.

For that, I believe I need to register it on facebook.com/insights and get an app_id.

But When I try to open the page it shows only the header and footer, no content.

And I've tried in different computers with different Facebook accounts.

Did anything change or is Facebook indeed having problem with that page?

Thanks

Comment: If you don’t have any objects yet that insights are available for, then of course it doesn’t show any.

Comment: Yeah I think that's pretty obvious. But it's not like it's showing no object. It is showing no content at all. Including the options to Add a new page.

Comment: That page does not offer that option. To create a new app, you need to go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Comment: Even though it was already created there, the insights page is still empty. Maybe it was discontinued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, oddly enough, 3 weeks later the page is just back to normal.
And not just for me, but for 3 other Facebook Insight user's that I contacted in this mean while.